# command to save terminate output to a file in unix

Tags: unix

I want to save the unix terminal command and out to store in a file for a session. Because some time unix command output are so large, so we con not get back by scrolling up in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Why not pipe the output to [tee](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee) ? That will record in a file *and* dump to the console so you can see in real time what's going on.

```
$ mycommand | tee filename.log
```

Note that the above will only record `stdout`. If you need to record `stderr` too, then redirect accordingly:

```
$ mycommand 2>&1 | tee filename.log
```

(assuming you're using `sh` or a compatible shell - most likely)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `script filename` command.